# date_select dont show in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using devise 1.5.3 with rails 3.1.3, ruby 192, Im following this tutorial: http://ecuadoronrails.org/creando-un-sistema-de-autenticacion-de-usuarios-en-ruby-on-rails/#more-186

**in my views I have:**

```
<div><%= f.label :fecha_de_vencimiento %></br>  
  <%= f.date_select(:fecha_vencimiento, :start_year => 1901, :end_year => 2011, :include_blank => true) %>
```

but when I go to **http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up**

i get a **textfield with the label**  like any other field...not a date_select field

what im doing wrong? do I need to install any gem??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my config/locales/en.yml

month_names: [~, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hundred percent sure, but did you try that ?

```
  <%= f.date_select :fecha_vencimiento, {:start_year => 1901, :end_year => 2011, :include_blank => true} %>
```

Comment: nop, when I fill the form and try to sign_i I get:ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in Devise::RegistrationsController#create